# BizTalk and MQ fail when on the same server

Tags: ibm-mq, biztalk

I have BizTalk running on a virtual box, that hits my server. It can post messages to the MQ queues without any problem. The issue is when I run BizTalk, which is installed on the same server as MQ, the MQSAgent throws this error:

> The adapter has encountered an 'Access Denied' error while attempting to contact the COM+ object on the MQSeries server. Ensure the BizTalk account is added to the Role on the MQSAgent COM+ application*

The virtual box, uses the same MQSAgent as the server. Just to be sure I checked to make sure everything is set up, ie User is added to the COM group and has the role of creater/owner.

I haven't found anything on line where a developer is having the same issue.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I never faced this issue but it seems to be a known issue by Microsoft. please check the following [Known Issues with the MQSeries Adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/known-issues-with-the-mqseries-adapter) (learn.microsoft.com)

Comment: Thanks, I've been through all the items listed on the link, still access denied.